# NiFi GetFTP cannot read from IBM Z/OS

Tags: apache-nifi, zos

I'm trying to read some files from Z/OS in a path like this: `MY.PATH.FTP.DIR`.
But I cannot read files from NiFi GetFTP or other processors. However I can see files from ftp client by changing directory (cd) to `MY.PATH.FTP.DIR`.

Comment: Is there an error being produced by GetFTP? If so please provide the error message and corresponding stacktrace from nifi-app.log

Comment: Do you have authority to read those files you say you can see but cannot get?

Comment: What FTP commands do you use while trying to access the dataset? There is no such thing as a "path" with z/OS datasets. What is `MY.PATH.FTP.DIR`? A sequential dataset? VSAM? A partitioned dataset? An HFS dataset?

Comment: @cschneid I can see and get files through win/linux FTP client. But cannot see by NiFi `GetFTP` or `ListFTP`.

Comment: @ piet.t It is a path on IBM mainframe OS. In ftp client I can `cd` to this path and read files.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is simple. Microsoft and Apache FTP software automatically assumes ASCII for text and for binary, well binary.  So when you signify text, you're getting an unconverted EBCDIC text stream which shows up on the host as gibberish.  That is unless you're into hex dumps like some of us. I had the same problem with MS when they added FTP into File Mangler but not the old MS/DOS copy.  Ran into it again using Apache's FTP Java API in net-commons (or net-something, it's been awhile). Unicode makes it a little more interesting. Yeah, you can look at directories and navigate around because by definition all that data transfer is always in ASCII.

I feel you pain, 
Mr. Bumpy  (anon)